# What is the keybind for the toggle workspaces?

Tags: interface, workflow

When you press ctrl+ --> you change from 3d view to compositing, to code workspace, to video editor, to tracking, to UV layout, etc..

Where are those keybinds to toggle workspaces? They don't appear in the keymapping on Input tab on user preferences.

I need to find and assig "UV layout workspace" to ctrl+shift+F10". It *has* to be a 3 combination keymap including functions keys.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Screen layouts toggle can be easily searched by "Ctrl Left Arrow" search in Key-Binding mode. Change there to what is needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In user preferences  input look for "set screen" (there are two of them):

[image]

you can change to what you said, as shown below:

[image]

Just click where there's the current key combination, and use the new combination) - save preferences if you need it to be permanent...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is a way to call a specific workspace. The way the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> shortcuts works are basically by rolling a table with workspaces on it.

But maybe there is a simple way to create that via a python script.

Comment: The markdown for keyboard keys is `<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`

Comment: Thanks, @batFINGER. I searched such function in the editor's icons but didn't thought about md. :(